# Why does jQuery's .css('letter-spacing') return a number if no spacing has been set?

Tags: jquery, css

I notice that jQuery's .css('letter-spacing') returns the number 0 if the text has not had a letter-spacing applied yet. (See http://jsfiddle.net/4xgb6xsp/3.) Once the text has a letter-spacing (uncomment the letter-spacing style) css() bring back the value in a string, like '2px'.

This is a bit inconvenient if you're trying to bump the letter spacing and you don't know if you're going to get a string or a number back from css().

Is this just a quirk of jQuery or is there something deeper here?

Thanks

```
<div id="test">Hello World</div>
<button id="space_up">Space Up</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is actually trying to do you a favor here.  The computed style for that property, if it hasn't been explicitly set to a different value, will be "normal".  This normalizing allows you to have a slightly easier conversion process.  Instead of checking if the computedStyle is equal to "normal", and if not, using parseInt to get the value, you can simply use parseInt for both:

```
var letterSpace = parseInt(letterSpace, 10);
```

Updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4xgb6xsp/6/

Comment: The initial value `normal` evaluates to `0` in practice. Although CSS specifications allow browsers to assign a nonzero value to `normal`, no browser is known to do that.

Answer (score 0):

as [jQuery.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) returns the computed style properties for the first element in the set of matched elements, i think, if the `letter-spacing` property is not set, then the default computed value (the value after the browser has computed all the factors that affect those values) is returned, which is 0. 
See :: [jQuery.css() source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L339)

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt()` to convert pixel string values to integers:

```
var lspacing = parseInt($('#test').css('letter-spacing'));
```

*Be sure to include the `+ 'px'` when you assign your adjusted values back to letter-spacing.*

```
$('#test').css('letter-spacing', adjustedlspacing + 'px');
```

Comment: It's a good idea to always include the second parameter, `base` for `parseInt`,  in case the number you're parsing starts with a 0 and cause it to be parsed as base 8